# SOQL query is not working for the relationships

Tags: soql

This query is not working

```
SELECT Engagement_Code__c,(select Opportunity_Name__c from Invoice__c__r) FROM opportunity
```

Here `Opportunity_Name__c` field in the `Invoice__c` related to `Id` in Opportunity

Can someone tell what I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Open the Schema for **Invoices__C** you will find the Lookup to **Opportunity** object.

On opening the field definition you would see something called as "*Child Relationship Name*" , Thats the name you can use in your innequeryry.

So if Child Relationship Name was "**Invoices**" then your Inner SOQL will be

```
SELECT Engagement_Code__c,(Select Opportunity_Name__c from Invoices__r) FROM Opportunity
```

Check the schema what your child Relationship Name is and see it work in SOQL.